# Is it possible to flush rsyslog?

Tags: rsyslog

I'm using the unix `logger` command to send a log to syslog. But it takes way too long on some machines to get to file. Is it possible to flush rsyslog so that it writes to disk faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid`
```

According to the man page for rsyslogd, this makes rsyslogd close all open files. So it will flush its log output to disk.